# DDD data layer and presentation layer

Tags: domain-driven-design

Hello I have a question regarding ddd layers:
I basically structured my folders in:

```
├───presentations
│     ├───controllers
│     ├───helpers
│     ├───protocols
├───modules
│   ├───domain   #interfaces of implemented command handler
│     ├───commands            #Commands interfaces & abstract implementations
│     ├───errors              #Errors & Error Types
│     ├───events              #Events interfaces & abstract implementations
│     ├───services            #services interfaces & abstract implementations
│   ├───infrastructure
│     ├───persistence #repositories implementations
```

but I have doubts about which layer I should create my use-cases, command handlers, commands implementations, events implementations.
my question is whether i should create in my modules / ** / infrastructure folder
or whether I should create a folder like:

```
├───DATA or APPLICATION
│    ├───dtos            #Commands interfaces & abstract implementations
│    ├───commands            #Commands interfaces & abstract implementations
│    ├───events              #Events interfaces & abstract implementations
│    ├───useCases            #services interfaces & abstract implementations
```

Another question: my presentation layer, should controllers be on that layer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder in ./modules/application and put your use cases there.
About where to put the command handlers, command implementations or events implementations should be in the `infrastructure` folder. Because probably they are going to be dependent of some infrastructure, like rabbitmq, or spring boot (if you are using java), or amazon SQS etc..
Yes, your controller folder should be inside the presentation, also if you have any CLI or Event controller that is triggered by outside.